# Why isn't the original value getting incremented twice even though I have two increments

Tags: c++, reference, increment, decltype

I'm new at programming and can someone explain to me how this code work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int a = 3, b = 4;
    decltype(a) c = a;
    decltype((b)) d = a;
    ++c;
    ++d;


    cout << c << " " << d << endl;
}
```

I'm quite confused how this code run as they give me a result of `4 4`, shouldn't be like `5 5`? Because it was incremented two times by c and d? I'm getting the hang of `decltype` but this assignment caught me confused how code works again.

Comment: decltype gives you the type of a variable so `decltype(a)` = `int` .  So it's the same as `int c = a`; I think you can take it from there.

Comment: @AdrianMole `d` is a reference as `decltype(paren-expr)` deduces to a reference type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ooh - missed that bit.

Comment: If you're new to C++, then don't mess about with `decltype` corner cases. This is a highly technical question that would trip up even veterans, and it's not helpful in understanding the basics of the language.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I see, I was reading C++ Primer and stumbled with this lesson. Thank you for the advice I'll take your word for it!

Comment: @Maki Yeah, not your fault at all. There's a *ton* of bad beginner C++ advice out there, and sifting through it is incredibly difficult (trust me, we all had to go through that at one point). Good luck :)

Comment: It's a bit baffling why a primer would jump in with `decltype()` so early. It's template engineering wizardry. Not for beginners.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`decltype(a) c = a;` becomes `int c = a;` so `c` is a copy of `a` with a value of `3`.

`decltype((b)) d = a;` becomes `int& d = a;` because `(expr)` in a `decltype` will deduce a reference to the expression type.

So we have `c` as a stand alone variable with a value of `3` and `d` which refers to `a` which also has a value of `3`.  when you increment both `c` and `d` both of those `3`s becomes `4`s and that is why you get `4 4` as the output

Answer (score 8):

This code can be rewritten as:

```
int a = 3;  //Forget about b, it is unused

int c = a;  // copy (c is distinct from a)
int& d = a; // reference (a and d both refers to the same variable)

++c;
++d;
```

`c` is a distinct copy of `a`, incrementing it by `1` gives `4`.

`d` is a reference of `a` (but still not related to `c`), incrementing it also give `4` (the only difference is that `a` is also modified since `a` and `d` both refers to the same variable).